# Pattern for instantiating a single object, while maintaining testability

Tags: javascript

When my application boots, it instantiates Redis client object:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient(REDIS_URL);
```

I maintain a proxy object `myRedisClient` that exposes a promisified version of the API exposed by the client object:

```
const get = (key) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        redisClient.get(key, (err, resp) => 
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(resp))

const myRedisClient = { get };
```

It feels wrong to simply have `redisClient` implicitly instantiated, so I would like to put it in a method to be explicitly called:

```
let redisClient = null;
const init = () => redisClient || redis.createClient(REDIS_URL);
const myRedisClient = { init, get};
```

`get` needs access to `redisClient`. If `get` is in the same file as the `redisClient` variable then this is straightforward.

If `get` is in a separate file, however, `redisClient` could be made available by closing over it and adding `redisClient` as an argument to `get`.

```
// my-redis-client.js
import get from './get';

let redisClient = null;
const init = () => redisClient || redis.createClient(REDIS_URL);
const myRedisClient = { init, get(key) => get(redisClient, key) };

// get.js
const get = (redisClient, key) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        redisClient.get(key, (err, resp) => 
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(resp));
```

Finally, I want to be able to stub out `redisClient`, and I suppose I could then stub out `redis.createClient` (eg using the stubbing capability built into a test runner) before I call it from a test.

Does this though process sound sane, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels wrong to simply have `redisClient` implicitly instantiated

No, there's nothing wrong with that, it's exactly what your app should do on startup.

What is wrong with `redisClient` is that it is a stateful global variable and that your `myRedisClient` *implicitly depends* on it. Putting the initialisation of `redisClient` in a method to be called explicitly doesn't solve either of those problems.

To be able to stub out `redisClient` either

- Be explicit in that it is a global variable by installing `global.redisClient = …` on startup. For mocking you can easily overwrite the global (if you don't want to run multiple tests with independent mocks in parallel).
- Be explicit about the dependency and

  - use a module system where `myRedisClient.js` depends on a `redisClient.js` module that exports a "global" static value, but have your test system use a module loader with dependency injection
  - make a constructor or factory function for your `myRedisClient` so that you can initialise it by explicitly passing the `redisClient` to it.

That last solution seems to be in the spirit of what you were trying to do. It should look like this:

```
// my-redis-client.js
default export function init(redisClient) {
    const get = util.promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);

    return { get };
}
// main.js
import initMyClient from 'my-redis-client'
const myRedisClient = initMyClient(redis.createClient(REDIS_URL));
```

Comment: Thank you. In my example, `redisClient` is not a global variable (I accept my code snippet was unclear), but a module-level variable (for whatever flavour of modules). Would a tweaked version of your solution to move the `redis.createClient...` into an `init` own-function on the `myReditClient` be OK? Finally, the injection of the `redisClient` in your solution occurs in the init function. In my proposed solution it happens in the `get` function itself. This is six of one and half-a-dozen...? Or not?

Comment: I still would recommend to separate the creation of the `redisClient` from the creation of the `myRedisClient`, like `initMyRedisClient(getGlobalRedisClient)`. (Whether you use a factory function, a constructor function, or an `init` method for your `myRedisClient` doesn't really matter). Notice you might still have the singleton problem for the `const myRedisClient` and the `const REDIS_URL` - depending on what parts of your code you want to test in which granularity, you might have to use dependency injection there as well.

Comment: Regarding whether to inject `redisClient` into `get` or in `init`, my thinking was that you'd want to unit-test `myRedisClient.get(…)` not `get` alone. The injection into `myRedisClient` should be the same no matter how many methods you will ultimately have there, so `init` is the natural place. Of course if you want to have `get` defined in its own file (imo not really necessary), you will need to pass the reference there as well, you won't get around that. You might want to consider using a `.redisClient` instance property and defining `get` as a method to be called.